# Need to understand how to add values in a loop

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numint, sum, a, b, ctr;
    cout << "Enter the number of intervals: ";
    cin >> numint;
    ctr = 0;
    while (ctr != numint) 
    {
        cout << "Enter the lower and upper bounds of the interval: ";
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        ctr++;
    }
    cout << "The sum of the " << numint << " intervals is: [" << a << "," << b << "]";
    return 0;
}
```

I need to add the upper bounds of the interval (a) and lower bounds of the interval (b). This depends on the amt of intervals there are.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Do you need to add in 3 intervals (for example), `a+a+a`, and `b+b+b`, and then the final result `finalA+finalB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here:

```
cout << "The sum of the " << numint << " intervals is: [" << a << "," << b << ]";
```

you are not adding the values but instead just printing them

instead use some accumulator variable and do the math before printing it, like:

```
int main()
{
int numint,sum,a,b,ctr;

int result = 0;

cout << "Enter the number of intervals: ";
cin >> numint;
ctr=0;
while (ctr!=numint)
{
    cout << "Enter the lower and upper bounds of the interval: ";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    ctr++;
   }
    result = a + b ;
    cout << "The sum of the " << numint << " is: " <<  result;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: For example if there are 3 intervals, what i need is to add (a+a+a) and show the end result and also add (b+b+b) and show the end result.

Answer (score 0):

As for what I understood from the question, you first need a `int resultA=0` and another for b, and keep adding in the loop:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numint,sum,a,b,ctr;

int result = 0;
int resultA=0;
int resultB=0;
cout << "Enter the number of intervals: ";
cin >> numint;
ctr=0;
while (ctr!=numint)
{
    cout << "Enter the lower and upper bounds of the interval: ";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    resultA+=a;
    resultB+=b;
    ctr++;
   }
    result = resultA + resultB ;
    cout << "The sum of the " << numint << " is: " <<  result;


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numberOfIntervals;
    int lowerBound;
    int upperBound;
    int counter;

    int lowerBoundSum = 0;
    int upperBoundSum = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of intervals: ";
    cin >> numberOfIntervals;
    counter = 0;
    while (counter != numberOfIntervals) {
        cout << "Enter the lower and upper bounds of interval " 
             << counter << ": ";
        cin >> lowerBound;
        cin >> upperBound;
        lowerBoundSum += lowerBound;
        upperBoundSum += upperBound;
        counter++;
    }
    cout << "The sum of the lower bounds is " << lowerBoundSum 
         << endl;
    cout << "The sum of the upper bounds is " << upperBoundSum 
         << endl;


    return 0;
}
```